# How to calculate date difference in a measure in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

i am trying to use measure to calculate the number of days between two date and the further use of calculation,

when i am typing my column name in DATEDIFF function its not showing in dax measure.

but the moment i'm typing the number of days manually it works.

```
ClosingDays = 
30 * [Total Closing] / [Total Sales]
```

Please let me know how to get number of days in a month in measure.

Comment: Can you add an example of the data and structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use an iterator function to evaluate the row context, like the X series of DAX commands, SUMX,MINX, MAXX etc.

Assuming you have two columns, Start Date and End Date, you'll need a measure along the lines of:

```
No of Days = SUMX('Table', DATEDIFF('Table'[StartDate], 'Table'[EndDate], DAY))
```

[image: No of Days in a measure]

You can of course, add a calculated column using DATEDIFF if your data structure supports it, and then create a measure on that references that column.